# javascript ajax api request google books

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, request

I'm trying to grab specific data from my ajax request.

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn9783125785021

I wanna grab the title of the book which is under items->volumeInfo->title

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn9783125785021',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var title = data.items.volumeInfo.title;
                }
                });
```

this doesn't seem to be working though. The var returns with nothing when I try to print out it's value.

EDIT: 
Console data log is showing this: http://puu.sh/mZ2lw/3012bba146.png

I notice that it is actually under, items->0->volumeInfo->title

However

```
var title = data.items.0.volumeInfo.title;
```

would return an error unexpected int obviously... Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest adding an error handler and see if anything shows up there.

Comment: You should use bracket notation to access array items in javascript. eg obj.items[1].volumeInfo.title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var title = data.items[0].volumeInfo.title;

Thanks Darshan.